# How to guarantee that $f$ is piecewise constant

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we have a function on a compact interval $f\colon[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $t\in [a,b]-\{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\}$ there exist $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(\tau) = c$ for all $\tau\in [t,t+\epsilon]$ and some $c\in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is a step function (piecewise constant)? Can we guarantee that? It could happen that some $t_i\in \{t_1,t_2,\dots,t_n\}$ fulfills the condition, but the point is that this is a finite set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not the case in general. For example take the function $f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}_{\left[\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n}\right)}$$

Then $f$ is right continuous, so it is easy to see that your condition holds for all $t\in(0,1)$ but $f$ it is not a step function (as it takes an infinite number of values).

However, if you replace your condition with $f(\tau) = c$ for all $\tau\in [t-\epsilon,t+\epsilon]$ then $f$ is indeed a step function.